# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymongo' with Docker and Airflow

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, airflow

I'm currently using Docker with [puckel/Airflow](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow) to run Airflow
I installed pymongo successfully but when calling the import of pymongo, it still fails to find the module.

I added below codes into the Dockerfile above the other RUN before rebuilding

1st attempt

`RUN pip install pymongo`

2nd attempt

`RUN pip install pymongo -U`

I built them with

`docker build --rm -t puckel/docker-airflow .`

Pymongo does install successfully but when I do run the webserver with a simple import of dags I still get the error

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/mongo_hook.py", line 22, in <module>
     from pymongo import MongoClient
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymongo'
```

Comment: what's your folder name?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by copying my `requirements.txt` file in the root.

In fact in `puckel/docker-airflow`'s Dockerfile it executes [entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/master/script/entrypoint.sh#L26) witch pip install packages from `/requirements.txt` if the file exists. So we are sure our packages are installed.

You can add in the `Dockerfile` :

```
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
```

**Or**

in a `docker-compose.yml` add a volume to your container:

```
volumes:
  - ./requirements.txt:/requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same symptom. I fixed it by adding `&& pip install pymongo \` to `puckel/airflow:Dockerfile`, near the other `pip install` commands and rebuilding the image.

Here's what I tried that did not fix the problem:

1. Adding `pymongo` to `requirements.txt` and mounting the file. I verified that the module was loaded as expected via log messages in `docker-compose` startup and by connecting to my worker and webserver instances and seeing that the module was available in the Python environment using `help("modules")` but the module was not available to my Airflow DAGs
2. Adding `--build-arg PYTHON_DEPS="pymongo"` as a parameter to my `docker build` command. (Note: for modules other than `pymongo` this step fixed `module not found` errors, but not for `pymongo`. In fact, I did not see any log record of `pymongo` being installed during `docker build` when I set this)

Answer (score 0):

Could you, try

```
RUN pip3 install pymongo
```

and report back. It might happen if you have multiple versions of Python. pip3 will make sure you are installing the module for Python 3.x.

Comment: Just ran with pip3 and it didnt work :(
The webserver is still running, however, the DAGS is imported mongo in shoots out errors.

Answer (score 0):

When you built the puckel/Airflow Docker image, did you add `mongo` to `AIRFLOW_DEPS` in your build arguments?

e.g. `docker build --rm --build-arg AIRFLOW_DEPS="mongo" -t puckel/docker-airflow .`

Answer (score 0):

I has similar experience for mysql hook and solved.

My experience is check if the module could be imported in pure python enviroment first.

Some time, the pack you installed is not the airflow wanted.

For your case, you could check in following step.
1. jump into the docker container
   docker exec -it  /bin/bash
2. launch  python assuming you has use python 3.X version
   python
3. check the module in python enviromnet
   import pymonggo
   # other test script if you to check.
if you facing error, pls solve it in python environment first and then go back to airflow.

=======================================================
I Just double checked the airflow github source code and realized that mongo db is not default hook in original source code.

In case case, you might need go further into pymongo package to study how to install & compile it and related dependence.